# In AS3 what will getTimer() return when the value is larger than the maximum int

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, int

Per [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) getTimer() is:

> Used to compute relative time. For a Flash runtime processing ActionScript 3.0, this method  returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash runtime virtual machine for ActionScript 3.0 (AVM2) started.

Since getTimer returns a int which:

> The int class lets you work with the data type representing a 32-bit signed integer. The range of values represented by the int class is -2,147,483,648 (-2^31) to 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1)

What will getTimer() return after the 2,147,483,647 millisecond? That would roughly be 24.85 straight days of running I think. Not a usual situation but for digital signage and kiosk context that is entirely feasible.

Should getTimer() be avoided in these situations? Would a Date.UTC() object be safer since it returns a Number type?

Comment: I will be back in 25 days, to know the right answer!

Comment: Awesome! I don't have an extra machine otherwise I'd join you.

Comment: I'd use Date.UTC() regardless.  You'd have to do a check to see what the time was, reset another custom property to cary the overflow.  Using Date.UTC() you capture the initial start time and just subtract it from the new time to get you value.

Comment: Agree with Gone3d I'd just go with Date.UTC(), both return millisecond precision so given the insight that the getTimer call returns a potentially smaller bit width representation that might have ill effects during bit overflow, doesn't provide any gain.  Just did a test and an int will wrap around above it's MAX_VALUE which was basically expected: http://snag.gy/iV6nC.jpg

Comment: Good responses. Date.UTC() is attractive for it's precision. I wonder what the performance differences are between Date.UTC and geTimer() — a test is in order, hopefully I'll remember to compare. Evidence of the wrap-around flipping over to negative is surprising and interesting. I mainly was wondering if getTimer() would throw an error, but after talking it through that seems unlikely, though I'd still be interested to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it will loop back on itself, just as int will.

```
var nt:int = int.MAX_VALUE + 10; //outputs -2147483639
var nt2:int = int.MIN_VALUE + 9; //outputs -2147483639
```

As you can see, `MAX + 10` is the same as `MIN + 9` (have to account for the min value itself, obviously). So when you hit that 24 day mark, it will possibly look like -24 days and start going back up.

There is also a chance that the function itself doesn't return the actual time, but something along these lines:

```
return timer % int.MAX_VALUE;
```

That will reset the time each time it hits the MAX_VALUE to 0, using simple modulus. I honestly would not be surprised if this is what they do (since you don't want a negative runtime, obviously)